# Independence of $\text{DC}(\mathbb{R})$ from $\text{ZF}+\text{AC}_\omega$, proof

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, forcing

I've read the proof of the independence of the axiom of dependent choice $\text{DC}$ from $\text{ZF}+\text{AC}_\omega$ in Jech's *The Axiom of Choice*, but there he proves it in $\text{ZFA}$ and then invokes some transfer theorem, making hard to pinpoint the set where $\text{DC}$ fails in the symmetric extension.

My question is how to define a symmetric model in which $\text{ZF}+\text{AC}_\omega+\neg\text{DC}(\mathbb{R})$ holds.

Can I re-use in some "cheap" way the construction defined in Jech's proof I mentioned above?
Any hint?

Thanks!

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/178914/7206

Comment: There's a symmetric extension of $L$ satisfying ZF + $AC_{\omega}$ + $\neg \Pi^1_2$-DC. This is optimal since ZF proves $\Sigma^1_2$-DC. See "A model of second-order arithmetic satisfying AC but not DC" by Friedman, Gitman, and Kanovei, particularly sections 9 and 10.